# Make a border to the areas in the image maps

Tags: html

I am trying to add a border around an Image Map Areas.

Here is an example of an Image map with 3 sectors.

```
<body>
<img src="trees.gif" usemap="#green" border="0">
<map name="green">
<area shape="polygon" coords="19,44,45,11,87,37,82,76,49,98" href="http://www.trees.com/save.html">
<area shape="rect" coords="128,132,241,179" href="http://www.trees.com/furniture.html">
<area shape="circle" coords="68,211,35" href="http://www.trees.com/plantations.html">
</map>
</body>
```

If somehow i could place a border with 2 pixel with around the area's it would be great.

Comment: Easiest would be to edit the image. There's no way to automatically add borders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to do this with straight HTML/CSS. You can with SVG though that is not supported by IE6/7.

You may find this JavaScript plugin of use: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/ particularly its `stroke` settings.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best that can be done is something like

```
<body>
  <style> a { border: 2px solid rgba(255,0,0,.1); }
          a:hover{ border:2px solid rgba(0,0,255,.3); }</style>
  <div style="position:relative">
    <img src="trees.gif" width="1727" height="1434" />
    <a href="http://www.trees.com/furniture.html"
         style="display:block; width:247px; height:66px; left: 48px; top: 275px;
         position:absolute;"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Although you lose some of the flexibility of `<area>`s, (polygons), you gain all the style capabilities of `<a>`s.

Comment: This poses issues with responsive setups

Comment: @fseminario Right, this is something of a minimum example. To make it responsive, you have some javascript that listens to resize events and scales the sizes appropriately. I currently have a solution like this running as expected.

Comment: @fseminario it doesn't if you use percentage units. I used this technique to create a responsive map of the UK with map markers that scaled perfectly.