# how to give border to area coordinates in image using css

Tags: html, css

I have tried this code i am getting the area but border of that area is not getting displayed

```
<area shape="poly"coords="288,25,283,12,278,6,272,4,266,3,252,3,247,6,240,10,236,14,235,18,236,26,236,33,237,37,238,32,244,22,250,18,256,16,261,12,268,12,278,15,282,19,290,24" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('finRot1').checked=!document.getElementById('finRot1').checked;" />
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499446/make-a-border-to-the-areas-in-the-image-maps

Answer (score 0):

You can try a jQuery and  maphilight:

http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

demo is available here:

http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html