# Highlight rectangle in imagemap

Tags: javascript, css, imagemap

Bit of a newbie question and not much comes to light with google, at least nothing recent.

I have an imagemap that is simply a horizontal toolbar.
What I want to do ultimately is draw an rgba rectangle overtop of the area to when the mouse hovers over it.

But I can't get it to do much at all here.  It seems area elements work a bit differently.  How do I do it in pure javascript please.  No jquery.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
  function tellname(txt){
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=txt;
  }
</script>
<style>
  .highlight:hover {
      outline: 1px solid orange;
  }
</style>
    <img src="toolbar.png" usemap="#toolbar" />
    <map name="#toolbar">
        <area class="highlight" shape="rect" coords="0,0,25,25" onclick="tellname('Centre')"/>
        <area class="highlight" shape="rect" coords="25,0,50,25" onclick="tellname('Reset Camera')" />
        <area class="highlight" shape="rect" coords="50,0,75,25" onclick="tellname('Camera Preset')" />
        <area class="highlight" shape="rect" coords="95,0,120,25" onclick="tellname('Stop Render')" />
        <area class="highlight" shape="rect" coords="120,0,145,25" onclick="tellname('Restart Render')" />
        <area class="highlight" shape="rect" coords="160,0,185,25" onclick="tellname('Pause Render')" />
        <area class="highlight" shape="rect" coords="190,0,205,25" onclick="tellname('Start Render')" />
    </map>
    <div id='info'</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: areas have no style. Build a real toolbar. Using Images to layout like that has been deprecated for decades.

Answer (score 0):

`<map name=#toolbar">` should be `<map name="toolbar">`.

However, I played with map and area a while, but could not make it work as you need.
There is some problem with setting the hover for `<map>` and `<area>`.  Maybe an expert can explain why.

(1)  Here's an alternative, using separate images for your links:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    img:hover {
    border:2px solid red; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<a href="page1.html"><img src="img_1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="page2.html"><img src="img_2.jpg" /></a>
<a href="page3.html"><img src="img_3.jpg" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

(2)  Or, see this post: [Make a border to the areas in the image maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499446/make-a-border-to-the-areas-in-the-image-maps)
which includes a reference to [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#shapes), *a very flexible library for creating image maps of many types*.

I use ImageMapster to dynamically create image maps of exploded parts diagrams.  For each image, its related map is created from map coordinates in a database.  As I scroll over the sections of the image, details of the mapped area appear in a text box, just as you want to do with function `tellname(txt)`.

[image]