# how could I give hover effect(outline color red) to the area elements only?

Tags: javascript, html, hover, area

below is my for image hover effect. i need some effect when i hover below coordinates

```
        <div class="cover">
      <div class="cover-image">
        <img src="images/cover.png" usemap="#powerpuffgirls" alt="" class="map"/>
          <map name="powerpuffgirls" id="map-area">
            <area  alt="" title="About Us" href="#" shape="poly" coords="213,234,208,240,196,245,185,248,179,256,170,260,163,262,157,265,148,265,142,270,135,266,130,270,130,282,130,354,114,366,111,314,112,306,114,283,108,274,101,266,89,262,79,265,68,264,60,256,48,254,40,249,33,243,30,237,22,235,22,231,22,228,26,222,33,229,31,224,31,220,30,217,31,212,28,210,30,206,30,203,29,202,28,200,28,198,29,196,32,191,36,189,39,186,38,184,36,182,35,180,35,177,30,179,29,176,30,170,34,169,35,166,36,163,38,161,38,158,38,154,40,152,43,149,40,147,39,143,46,145,46,142,47,139,49,138,51,137,53,136,54,134,62,139,64,136,70,135,69,132,74,129,84,137,92,138,98,137,96,133,100,130,110,134,117,132,116,128,125,131,134,135,139,129,148,129,149,124,157,126,161,135,168,138,175,141,178,137,185,144,191,153,200,156,199,167,206,168,209,177,217,182,212,191,210,199,215,206,217,213,214,220,215,230" style="outline:none;" target="_self"/>
                    </map>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499446/make-a-border-to-the-areas-in-the-image-maps

Answer (score 0):

.cover:hover area {border: 1px solid #F00;}